# I am getting 'Error: Cannot find module '@react-native-community/cli-tools' while creating my first react native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting 'Error: Cannot find module '@react-native-community/cli-tools' while creating my first react native project with ' npx react-native init AwesomeProject ' command. I have fellow all the instruction mention in react native documentation Link - ( https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup ) . I have java -version = 11.0.17, node.js version = 18.12.1[error Image of cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wTZR.png)

how to resolved this issue & create my new react app

Answer (score 0):

In your project, run:

```
npm install --save-dev @react-native-community/cli-tools
```